# How do I pass data from another page?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have two forms. one is Main Entry Form and other is District. In District form I Add district and i want that the District add i in District Table Show in Main Entry Form District Combo Box.

```
private void Mian_Entry_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // TODO: THIS CODE LOAD DISTRICT TO COMBOBOX IN MAINENTRY FORM

        string q = string.Format("Select districtid, districtname from district");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(q, connection);
        sd.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            comboBoxEditdistrict.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
            //comboBoxEditdistrict.
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After `sd.Fill(dt);` you can set a session `Session["districtList"] = dt;` you can use this session wherever you want; `DataTable dt = Session["districtList"] as DataTable;`